# A Question on Theorem 4.3 of Stein-Shakarchi [Approximating measurable functions with step functions]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, pointwise-convergence, simple-functions

I am confused on a part of the proof of Theorem 4.3 from Stein and Shakarchi's *Real Analysis*:

> **Theorem 4.3** *Suppose $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then there exists a sequence of step functions $\{\psi_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ that converges pointwise to $f(x)$ for almost every $x$.*

> *Proof*: By the previous theorem, there are simple functions $\{\varphi_k\}$ so that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \varphi_k(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$. To approximate each $\varphi_k$ by a step function, we recall part (iv) of Theorem 3.4, which states that if $E$ is a measurable set of finite measure, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist cubes $Q_1,\ldots,Q_N$ such that $m(E \triangle \bigcup_{j=1}^{N} Q_j) \leq \epsilon.$ By considering the grid formed by extending the sides of these cubes, we see that there exist almost disjoint rectangles  $\tilde{R}_1,\ldots,\tilde{R}_M$ such that $\bigcup_{j=1}^{N} Q_j = \bigcup_{j=1}^{M} \tilde{R}_j.$ By taking closed rectangles $R_j$ contained in $\tilde{R}_j$ and slightly smaller in size, we find a collection of disjoint closed rectangles that satisfy $m(E \triangle \bigcup_{j=1}^{M} R_j) \leq 2 \epsilon$.  It follows from this observation and the definition of a simple function that for each $k$, there exists a step function $\psi_k$ and a measurable set $F_k$ so that $m(F_k) < 2^{-k}$ and $\varphi_k(x) = \psi_k(x)$ for all $x \notin F_k$.
>
> If we define $F = \bigcap_{\ell = 1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k > \ell}^{\infty} F_k$, then $m(F) = 0$, because $m(\bigcup_{k > \ell}^{\infty} F_k) \leq \sum_{k \geq \ell} m(F_k) \leq 2^{-\ell}$. For $x \notin F$, there exists $k_0$ so that $x \in \bigcap_{k > k_0} F_k^c$, so for all $k > k_0$ one has
> $$|f(x) - \psi_k(x)| \leq |f(x) - \varphi_k(x)| + |\varphi_k(x) - \psi_k(x)| = |f(x) - \varphi_k(x)|,$$
> and since $\lim_{k \to \infty} \varphi_k(x) = f(x)$ we conclude that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \psi_k(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \notin F$, as desired. $\quad \square$

---

**My confusion**:
I don't understand the point of constructing a finite union of *almost disjoint rectangles* from the finite union of cubes. Why is this step necessary? Does it not suffice to just consider the collection of (not necessarily disjoint) cubes?

---

For completeness, here are the book's definitions of step functions and simple functions:

A **step function** is a function of the form
$$f = \sum_{k = 1}^{N} a_k \chi_{R_k},$$

where $a_1,\ldots,a_N$ are constants (real numbers) and $R_1,\ldots,R_N$ are rectangles (in $\mathbb{R}^d$).

A **simple function** is a function of the form
$$f = \sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k \chi_{E_k}$$
where $a_1,\ldots,a_N$ are constants and $E_1,\ldots,E_N$ are measurable sets with finite measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To approximate each $\varphi_k$ with step functions, note that it suffices to approximate $f = \chi_E$, the characteristic function of some set $E$. If the $R_j$ were not disjoint, then
$$
f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^M \chi_{R_j}(x)
$$
will evaluate to a value more than $1$ for a point in the intersection of two cubes for instance, and this is a poor approximation to $\chi_E$ which takes values only in $\{0,1\}$. The point is that at most one of the $\chi_{R_j}(x)$ in the sum should register the value $1$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!